# size of every www folder in users' home

Tags: shell, size, du

I need to make a shell script to get the size of every www directory of my users home folder

```
I need somethings like
USERNAME - WWWdirsize
USERNAME - WWWdirsize
TOTAL www Size = ...
```

I know that I have to play with the du unix command

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the recursive size of a folder: `du -hs | cut -f 1`

So to get the size of each user's www folder:

```
ls /home | while read username; do echo "$username $(du -hs "/home/$username/public_html" | cut -f 1)"; done
```

Comment: Actually, that could be tweaked to only handle user that have a public_html directory: `ls /home | while read username; do test -d "/home/$username/public_html" && echo "$username $(du -hs "/home/$username/public_html" | cut -f 1)"; done`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
du -sh /home/*/public_html
```

Output on my system:

```
0       /home/brokeneggs/public_html
3.1G    /home/jonhall/public_html
178M    /home/stubuntu/public_html
```

You can do further parsing of the output if you want *only* usernames to appear, and not full paths, for instance.

Comment: Actually better and much more simple than my "while-loop" solution. I'm so used to looping through things in bash that I forgot you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

try this command to calculate:

```
du -sch .
```